# jquery show hide using same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ccfvkjyf/

```
$(".date-picking").click(function(){
    $('.display').show(); 
});
```

I want to display the text when click the intput box,But click another intput box close the text and reopen the text again by using same class.

Please give any idea

Comment: Be more specific about what the issue is.

Comment: $('.display').toggle();

Comment: If I click the first input field display the Loading text. Then I click the another field "loading text" close and open immediately. when i use toggle the text will be hidden,it does not show

Comment: When do you want the 'loading text' to disappear? When leaving the input field? On blur?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6e42x6jj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below logic:
on focus event save the focused input in variable and check it on next focus event. if same input focussed again then don't toggle otherwise toggle it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var focusedInput;
$(".date-picking").on('focus',function(){
  if(focusedInput!=$(this)){
        focusedInput=$(this); 
    $('.display').hide(1000); 
    $('.display').show(1000); 
  }
});
});
```

**[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccfvkjyf/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Might be you are trying to `hide` the `text` when you `blur` `input` field, so you could do that using `focus() and blur()` method, as below,

Click anywhere outside input hides text.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".date-picking").on("focus",function(){
 $('.display').show(); 
});
$(".date-picking").on("blur",function(){
 $('.display').hide(); 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="date-picking " name="arrival"  type="text" placeholder="sometext" value=""/>

<input class="date-picking " name="departure"  type="text" placeholder="sometext" value=""/>

<div class="display" style="display:none">Loading text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check this working snippet

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function () {

       function handler1() {
         $('.display').show(); 
        $(this).one("click", handler2);
    }

    function handler2() {
        $('.display').hide(); 
        $(this).one("click", handler1);
    }
    $(".date-picking").one("click", handler1);


    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="date-picking " name="arrival"  type="text" placeholder="sometext" value=""/>

<input class="date-picking " name="departure"  type="text" placeholder="sometext" value=""/>

<div class="display" style="display:none">Loading text</div>
```